# How to perl process and push multiple directories using simple code

Tags: perl

I am trying to get all sub directories and files inside 'dir1, dir2, dir3,dir4,dir5' like below and push it to another Dir. if I using this code I am getting everything. however, I need to process more directories like this. is there simple way to process all these 'dir1 to ... dirx' using simple code instead of assign each directories individually  below. Thanks in Advance

```
use File::Find::Rule;
my @pushdir;
my @pushdir1 = File::Find::Rule->directory->in('/tmp/dirx');
my @pushdir2 = File::Find::Rule->directory->in('/tmp/nextdir');
my @pushdir3 = File::Find::Rule->directory->in('/tmp/pushdir');
my @pushdir4 = File::Find::Rule->directory->in('/tmp/logdir');
my @pushdir5 = File::Find::Rule->directory->in('/tmp/testdir');

push @pushdir, @pushdir1,@pushdir2,@pushdir3,@pushdir4,@pushdir5;

my @Files;
foreach my $dir (@pushdir) {
    push @Files, sort glob "$dir/*.txt";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a subroutine:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Find::Rule;

my @dirnames = qw( dirx temp_dir testdir nextdir );
my @dirs_to_search = map { "/tmp/$_" } @dirnames;
my @files;
for my $dir (@dirs_to_search) {
    push @files, find_files_in_dir($dir);
}

sub find_files_in_dir {
    my ($dir) = @_;    
    my @subdirs = File::Find::Rule->directory->in( $dir );    
    my @txt_files;
    for my $subdir ( @subdirs ) {
        push @txt_files, sort glob "$subdir/*.txt";
    }
    return @txt_files;
}
```

Comment: sorry, one small change. directory structure is '/tmp/dirx', '/tmp/temp_dir', '/tmp/testdir', '/tmp/nextdir'  like this. if its not  ending with '/tmp/dir1..5', how to change ?.  I've edited the original question. thanks .

Comment: I suspect the OP was asking for a way to avoid enumerating the subdirectories of `/tmp`. As far as I can tell, your solution does exactly the same as the OP's code, but the abstraction of part of the process into a subrouitine has made it less clear

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want a list of all `*.txt` files contained in `/tmp` child directories and their descendants

That's easily done with a single `glob` call, like this

```
my @files = glob '/tmp/**/*.txt'
```